# How to persist download count in Grails

Tags: spring, grails

I want to persist total document count on couple of scenarios for multiple controller actions(list,show..etc) and for each and every download count should be incremented by one asynchronously.
  what is the best way to implement this scenario in Grails

Comment: This is StackOverflow. How about some actual code? Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: There was a [plugin for grails 2.x](https://github.com/urbansky/Counter), you could look how that was implemented and do the same thing?

Comment: This can be achieved by several ways like Interceptors,AOP.Out of that which is best way...

Comment: Please let me know if you have any idea about this?

Comment: I want to put this logic in one place.So that based the scenario controller action will be invoked out of multiple controller's action and specific counter will be increated